# WordPress Text Widget on Custom Sidebar

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am new to WordPress. I am creating a custom sidebar where I want to display only Text Widget on a Contact page. There will be different sidebar on other pages.

I know how to make different sidebars on different pages.

The issue is: 
I want to display specific text widget on the custom sidebar. How do I target specific text bar as well as how to pass its value on the code?

I tried to create text widget using

```
<?php the_widget('WP_widget_text');?>
```

What will be the instance and args in this code?

P.S: I am using Zerif-lite wordPress theme

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of `the_widget` function. The description from [the WordPress Codex article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) is:

> This template tag displays an arbitrary widget outside of a sidebar.

It shouldn't be used in a custom sidebar created with [`register sidebar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).

If you just have a sidebar layout, without a registered WordPress sidebar, then you should use `the_widget`.

The second parameter, `$instance`, is an array or query string of the widgets settings.

For example, to display the WordPress categories widget in a template you would use:

```
$instance = array(
    'title'        => __( 'Categories' ),
    'count'        => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 0,
    'dropdown'     => 0,
);

the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Categories', $instance );
```

If you are using a custom sidebar for the contact form you can use `get_sidebar` to display it in your template.

```
<?php get_sidebar('contact'); ?>
```

This would pull from the file `wp-content/yourTheme/sidebar-contact.php`. That sidebar can use `the_widget` directly to display your text widget or use [`dynamic_sidebar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) to display widgets added to the sidebar in the WordPress dashboard.